# Main Window not being displayed after being called

Tags: python, pycharm, widget, qr-code, pyside2

I am creating a program that uses a webcam to scan in staff and QR Code scanner to scan in patients through a COM port and once a patient has been successfully scanned the user should be moved into the main window (Serial Interface), but this problem keeps persisting where once the qr code has been scanned the qrcodescanner widget is closed and the serial interface never appears, even once it is called, this issue only happened once I added in the patient scanning process.
Here is the code -

WebcamWidget

```
class WebcamWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.scan_qr_code)
        self.serial_interface_shown = False  # Track if the interface is already open
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("./venv/TriMedika-Logo.png"))
        self.setWindowTitle("TriMedika Dongle Application")
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.label = QLabel()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.timer.start(100)  # Update every 100 milliseconds


    def scan_qr_code(self):
        ret, frame = self.camera.read()
        if ret:
            barcodes = pyzbar.decode(frame)
            for barcode in barcodes:
                data = barcode.data.decode("utf-8")
                if data.isdigit():
                    indexs = int(data)
                    if self.check_user_in_database(indexs) and not self.serial_interface_shown:
                        self.serial_interface_shown = True
                        self.close()
                        scan_patient_widget.show()
                        break

            frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            image = QImage(
                frame_rgb.data, frame_rgb.shape[1], frame_rgb.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888
            )
            self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))

    def show_qr_code_scanner(self, indexs):
        qr_code_widget = QRCodeScannerWidget(indexs)
        qr_code_widget.show()


    def check_user_in_database(self, indexs):
        # Perform a database lookup based on the user_id
        # Modify this function according to your database and table structure

        # Establish a connection to the database
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="root",
            password="",
            database="staffdetails"
        )  # Replace with your database path

        # Create a cursor object to execute SQL queries
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        # Execute the SQL query
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM staff WHERE indexs = %s", (indexs,))

        # Fetch the result
        result = cursor.fetchone()

        # Close the cursor and database connection
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

        if result is not None:
            return True  # User found in the database
        else:
            return False  # User not found in the database
```

QRCodeScannerWidget

```
class QRCodeScannerWidget(QWidget):
    qr_code_scanned = Signal(str)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("./venv/TriMedika-Logo.png"))
        self.setWindowTitle("TriMedika Dongle Application")
        self.init_ui()

        # Initialize COM port and scanning variables
        self.qr_scanner = None
        self.scanning = False

        # Create a QTextEdit widget to display results
        self.desc = QTextEdit(self)
        self.desc.setReadOnly(True)

        # Create a combo box to select the COM port
        self.typeBox = QComboBox(self)
        self.typeBox.addItem("COM1")
        self.typeBox.addItem("COM3")
        self.typeBox.addItem("COM6")
        self.typeBox.addItem("COM7")
        self.typeBox.addItem("COM8")

        # Create a button to start scanning
        self.scan_button = QPushButton("Start Scanning", self)
        self.scan_button.clicked.connect(self.on_scan_button_clicked)

        # Layout for QTextEdit, combo box, and Scan button
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.desc)
        layout.addWidget(self.typeBox)
        layout.addWidget(self.scan_button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def init_ui(self):
        palette = self.palette()
        palette.setColor(QPalette.Background, QColor("white"))
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.setPalette(palette)

    def open_com_port(self):
        # Open the COM port for scanning
        self.port = self.typeBox.currentText()  # You need to define typeBox in your code
        try:
            self.qr_scanner = serial.Serial(self.port, 9600, timeout=1)
            self.scanning = True
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error opening COM port: {str(e)}")

    def close_com_port(self):
        # Close the COM port
        if self.qr_scanner is not None:
            self.qr_scanner.close()
        self.scanning = False

    def read_qr_code_data(self):
        while self.scanning:
            try:
                qr_data = self.qr_scanner.readline().decode(errors='ignore').strip()
                if qr_data:
                    self.process_qr_data(qr_data)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error scanning QR code: {str(e)}")

    def on_scan_button_clicked(self):
        if not self.scanning:
            # Open the COM port and start scanning
            self.open_com_port()
            threading.Thread(target=self.read_qr_code_data).start()

            # Display initial message
            self.update_text_edit("Please scan the QR Code")

    def update_text_edit(self, text):
        # This slot will be called from the worker thread to update the QTextEdit
        self.desc.clear()
        self.desc.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.desc.append(text)

    def process_qr_data(self, qr_data):
        # Check the scanned QR data (assuming it's a valid patient ID)
        success = self.check_patient_number(qr_data)

        if success:
            # Close the COM port and stop scanning
            self.close_com_port()

            # Hide the QRCodeScannerWidget
            self.hide()

            # Show the SerialInterface
            show_serial_interface(qr_data)

        else:
            self.update_text_edit("Invalid Patient ID. Please scan a valid ID.")

    def check_patient_number(self, patient_number):
        try:
            # Establish a connection to the database
            conn = mysql.connector.connect(
                host="localhost",
                user="root",
                password="",
                database="patientdetails"
            )

            # Create a cursor object to execute SQL queries
            cursor = conn.cursor()

            # Execute the SQL query
            cursor.execute("SELECT name, hcn FROM patient WHERE HCN = %s", (patient_number,))

            # Fetch the result
            result = cursor.fetchone()

            # Close the cursor and database connection
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()

            if result is not None:
                return True, result[0], result[1]  # Patient found in the database
            else:
                return False, None, None  # Patient not found in the database

        except mysql.connector.Error as e:
            print(f"Error querying the database: {str(e)}")
            return False, None, None  # Database error
```

Welcome widget and Serial Interface

````
class WelcomeWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, serial_interface, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.serial_interface = serial_interface  # Store the reference to the SerialInterface instance
        self.name_label = QLabel()
        self.staff_id_label = QLabel()
        self.patient_info_label = QLabel()  # Add a label for patient information

        layout = QHBoxLayout()  # Use a Horizontal layout

        layout.addWidget(self.name_label)
        layout.addWidget(self.staff_id_label)
        layout.addWidget(self.patient_info_label)  # Add the patient information label

        back_button = QPushButton("Back to Login")
        back_button.setStyleSheet(
            "QPushButton { background-color: orange; color: white; border: none; padding: 4.5px; border-radius: 5px; }"
            "QPushButton:hover { background-color: #ff9800; }" 
            "QPushButton:pressed { background-color: #f57c00; }"
        )
        back_button.setMaximumWidth(175)
        back_button.clicked.connect(self.go_to_login_widget)
        layout.addWidget(back_button)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def set_user_info(self, Name, StaffID, PatientName=None, PatientHCN=None):
        self.name_label.setText(f"Welcome, {Name}")
        self.staff_id_label.setText(f"Staff ID: {StaffID}")

        if PatientName is not None and PatientHCN is not None:
            self.patient_info_label.setText(f"Patient Name: {PatientName}\nHCN: {PatientHCN}")
        else:
            self.patient_info_label.clear()  # Clear the patient info if not provided

    def go_to_login_widget(self):
        self.serial_interface.hide()
        login_widget.show()

class SerialInterface(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, indexs, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.width = 900
        self.height = 600
        self.logoSize = 200

        self.resize(self.width, self.height)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("./venv/TriMedika-Logo.png"))
        self.setWindowTitle("TriMedika Dongle Application")

        # Center window on screen
        self.center_window()

        # Init layout
        centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        centralLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        centralwidget.setLayout(centralLayout)

        # Group 1
        group1 = GroupClass(
            self,
            upload_data_to_database
        )

        # Group 2
        self.group2 = Group2(self)  # Use the custom Group2 class
        group2Layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.group2.setLayout(group2Layout)

        # Welcome Widget
        self.welcome_widget = WelcomeWidget(self)  # Pass the instance reference

        # Create a tab widget
        tabWidget = QTabWidget()

        # Create the first tab and add group1 to it
        tab1 = QWidget()
        tab1Layout = QVBoxLayout()
        tab1Layout.addWidget(group1)
        tab1.setLayout(tab1Layout)

        # Create the second tab and add group2 to it
        tab2 = QWidget()
        tab2Layout = QVBoxLayout()
        tab2Layout.addWidget(self.group2)
        tab2.setLayout(tab2Layout)

        tab3 = QWidget()
        tab3layout = QVBoxLayout()
        group3 = GraphTab()
        tab3layout.addWidget(group3)
        tab3.setLayout(tab3layout)

        # Add the tabs to the tab widget
        tabWidget.addTab(tab1, "Serial Monitor")
        tabWidget.addTab(tab2, "Recent Measurements")
        tabWidget.addTab(tab3, "Graph Data")

        # Add the widgets to the central layout
        centralLayout.addWidget(self.welcome_widget)
        centralLayout.addWidget(tabWidget)

        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)

        self.show()
        self.load_user_info(indexs)

    def center_window(self):
        desktop = QApplication.primaryScreen()
        screen_rect = desktop.availableGeometry()
        window_rect = self.geometry()
        x = screen_rect.width() // 2 - window_rect.width() // 2
        y = screen_rect.height() // 2 - window_rect.height() // 2
        self.move(x, y)

    def load_user_info(self, indexs):
        # Perform a database lookup based on the indexs
        # Modify this function according to your database and table structure

        # Establish a connection to the database
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="root",
            password="",
            database="staffdetails"
        )  # Replace with your database path

        # Create a cursor object to execute SQL queries
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        # Execute the SQL query
        cursor.execute("SELECT Name, StaffID FROM staff WHERE indexs = %s", (indexs,))

        # Fetch the result
        result = cursor.fetchone()

        # Close the cursor and database connection
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

        if result is not None:
            Name, StaffID = result
            self.welcome_widget.set_user_info(Name, StaffID)
        else:
            # User not found in the database, handle accordingly
            pass


def show_serial_interface(qr_data):
    interface = SerialInterface(qr_data)
    interface.show()

def show_scan_patient_id_widget(self):
    self.scan_patient_id_widget.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    login_widget = LoginWidget()
    webcam_widget = WebcamWidget()
    signup_widget = SignUpWidget()
    login_details_widget = LoginDetailsWidget()
    scan_patient_widget = QRCodeScannerWidget()

    login_widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    ```
````